# Is it possible to generate JSONSchema from database config?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Our application needs to accept input from 2 clients whose input payload is different. We cannot create data model in the application for the input data to validate each field. We need flexibility of managing the input JSON keys and their hierarchy in DB (thats why the below DB config). So, I was thinking if the same DB config can be used to generate the JSONSchema against which we can validate the inputs.

App 1 can send data like:

```
{
"user_details":{
  "fname":"John",
  "lname":"Smith",
  "address":{"city":"NY"}
  }
}
```

App 2 can send data like:

```
{
"license":{
  "number":"ABC123",
  "expired":true
  }
}
```

**DB table : fields**

```
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+--------+
| id | parent_id |    label     |  type  | required | app_id |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+--------+
|  1 |         0 | user_details | object | true     |      1 |
|  2 |         1 | fname        | string | true     |      1 |
|  3 |         1 | lname        | string | true     |      1 |
|  4 |         1 | address      | object | true     |      1 |
|  5 |         4 | city         | string | true     |      1 |
|  6 |         0 | license      | object | true     |      2 |
|  7 |         6 | number       | number | true     |      2 |
|  8 |         6 | expired      | string | false    |      2 |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Why not just use a database designed to store this type of data? A document store database.

Comment: @Relequestual: We don't want user to mess up the existing JSON structure when a new field is to be added, so we thought of providing a form UI to enter any new field, that's one reason to go with relational DB.

Comment: @Relequestual: Any other suggestion ? Or we need to go ahead with custom logic for it ?

Comment: There are too many unknowns for anyone to suggest a solution to your problem here. Sorry.

Comment: @Relequestual : Can you let me know list of unknowns so that I can think on that and see if I can include those in the design ?

Comment: You've made too many assumptions and you've not explained enough details. Anyway, it sounds like you're asking for a recommendation for a tool or library, which is off topic here.

Comment: I would re-ask your question giving MUCH more detail. Currently I have no idea what you are actually asking.

Comment: @Relequestual : Is it better now ?